# Small person who takes on a powerful task or job

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an English term for a small person who takes on a powerful task or job to feel bigger?

When I say "small", I'm not referring to physical size, but to pettiness and feelings of powerlessness.

Comment: A little Napoleon.

Comment: A little Hitler?

Comment: Tyrion Lannister?

Comment: Anybody great has started small and powerless;  that's the motivator of ambition:  getting  power to be able to change things (for good, for bad). So , that small guy is "ambitious".

Answer (score 5):

You might consider the term **petty tyrant**.

A petty tyrant is someone who abuses their generally small amount of power by wielding it capriciously or in a self-aggrandizing fashion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petty_tyranny

Comment: And maybe a *lilliputian tyrant.*